# Internet Explorer not loading external styelsheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer, bigcommerce

So, I'm working on a clients page that's hosted with BigCommerce and it appears that all of the custom styles I wrote are not being recognized by internet explorer. It works fine in all other browsers.

It's strange because IE sees the .css file, but when you click into the stylesheet in developer tools, none of code populates.

I don't have more than 31 stylesheets so that's not the issue. I'm at my wits end and any help would be greatly appreciated.

The website is www.bangsshoes.com.

The stylesheet is .../bangs.css

Comment: It looks like you are triggering a mobile style sheet for IE and not other browsers. So most likely you are browser sniffing somewhere in your code. bangsmobile.css

Comment: also you have a lot of performance issues, which is a code smell of other issues. For example you have several 404s, http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140724_V9_EYP/

Comment: Yeah there are a lot of things you can't fix within BC that have an affect on performance. The mobile stylesheet is triggered by the restive.js library which appends tags to the body depending on the device and resolution of screen. Not just for IE though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought, but you could:

a) try combining the styles into another style sheet which is being successfully incorporated or,

b) since this is just a reset, try another reset? or a modenizr? http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.min.js

Another test would be to comment out the other style sheets and see if that makes a difference-- it's possible another style sheet is interfering (though unlikely!)

Comment: Combining it into a stylesheet that was already loading successfully worked! Not sure why it hated my other one. Thanks!